# UIVisualEffectView creates a grey box instead of blurring

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I'm using a UIVisualEffectView to blur a section of the screen in SpriteKit like so:

```
let blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
let UIEffectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
UIEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height * 0.15)
self.view?.addSubview(UIEffectView)
```

But it appears as a grey shaded area instead of a blur. Strangely, it blurs whilst the GameCenter notification shows at the start, saying "Welcome back, (player)" - but once the notification disappears, it goes back to being a grey box.

Same applies to when you go into the multi-task view in iOS9, the preview has the section blurred, but when you go into the app, it reverts to being a grey shaded area again.

Any ideas why this is happening? It does the same in the simulators as well as physical hardware.

Comment: try light blur effect instead of dark

Comment: I did - same result.

Comment: can u post a screenshot ?

Comment: Just tried, but in the screenshot, the area is blurred?? It wasn't when I took the screenshot, but it recorded it as being blurred. Seems like it's blurring everywhere else except playing in-app.

Comment: Where is this piece of code ? Try to make your EffectView as a property.

Comment: It's in didMoveToView, I've tried moving the "let blur:UIBlurEffect" to a property, but nothing's changed

Comment: Is self.view a custom view you built?

Comment: Yes, but it does the exact same in a non-custom view, I've just tried it.

Comment: Track down the error by lowering your `UIEffectView` alpha to 0: is the view you are trying to blur actually extending behind the effect?

Comment: No, move the effect view not the blur effect

Comment: Lowering the alpha just reduces the transparency of the grey box, and the scene I want to blur is definitely behind it as it goes grey when under the grey box. My scene isn't static, does that have anything to do with why it isn't calculating the blur?

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit underneath? I had the same issue before, [check out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442859/use-uivisualeffectview-to-create-a-blur-view-correct-on-simulator-but-not-on-ip)

Comment: @ValarMorghulis I was!! Thanks I don't know why that isn't made more obvious! I ended up taking a screenshot and then blurring the screenshot and overlaying it.

Comment: Feel the same. This issue took me several days. I hated that. I ended up creating a screen shot image, blur it with some effect, then add that as a SKNode to the SpriteKit. All I know is: try to avoid both UIKit and SpriteKit at the same time. there are lots of weird headaches!

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Yeah I did the exact same method. It's annoying that you can't blur moving scenes using that method though, unless you constantly took screenshots and blurred them.

Comment: the scene is moving? or the blur mask is moving?

Comment: @ValarMorghulis I was going to make the scene continue to move in the background, but I decided just to have the scene pause when it was blurred because it was easier to program that way!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same headache before [use UIVisualEffectView to create a blur view, correct on simulator but not on iphone & ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442859/use-uivisualeffectview-to-create-a-blur-view-correct-on-simulator-but-not-on-ip), it turns out weird stuff can happen when you mess `UIKit` together with `SpriteKit`. I would suggest use `SKEffectNode` to do the blur job, instead of `UIVisualEffectView`.