# use UIVisualEffectView to create a blur view, correct on simulator but not on iphone & ipad

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, blur, uivisualeffectview

The goal: create a blur view in app.

The code I use:

```
func createBlurBackgroundView() 
{
    if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() 
    {
        if blurredSubView == nil || blurredSubView.superview == nil 
        {
            print("Create blurred background view")
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
            blurredSubView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurredSubView.frame = self.bounds
            self.insertSubview(blurredSubView, atIndex: 0)
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        print("Transparency disabled!! no blur view")
    }
}
```

The result:
everything works fine on the simulator:

[image]

But when I ran it on the iphone and ipads, it looks like:
[image]

PLEASE NOTE I DIDN'T CHANGE THE "REDUCE TRANSPARENCY" SETTINGS!

Then when I want to take a snapshot of this black background without blur, guess what?! in the photo stream, I saw exactly the correct blur view picture...

Also, when I double clicked home button, and look at the multi-task interface, I saw the blur view effect!

[image]

More Info:
I use iphone6s, ipad air2, both iOS 9.3.1
Xcode version 7.3

I'm so tired on trying to solve this problem, I tried other methods like take snapshot image and then apply blur effect on the image, but has other bugs and other CONs

Comment: Did you check what `UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()` returns?

Comment: @jelly yes, please check my code, there is print information, and I checked the settings too

Comment: Where do you call `createBlurBackgroundView() ` ?

Comment: @jelly generally, I call it in initialization, also tried in layoutsubview function too though.

Comment: What about the background of your view? Not sure how the blur should look like over a black background.

Comment: @Jelly generally there are colored shapes, as you can see in the first pic. I really doubt if the problem is a simple mistake like forgot add some views. By the way, the underlying view is a skscene , this should not be a problem because I can see the blur view when I change to multi task interface or take a screen shot. So it must be there! But why I cannot see at the first place?

Comment: Well if you do not use autolayout (if you do you must make sure your subivew updates with the size of its superview) or other graphics tool (like `SpriteKit` with which blur effect does not work) aside of `UIKit` it should work.

Comment: @Jelly thanks I'll try a simpler example project to test this later.

Comment: I reproduced your code changing self.background property from clearColor to my own pattern color. And it works fine on iPhone 6.

Comment: @Jelly Maybe it's because SpriteKit. when I test with pure UIKit, no problem.

Comment: If you use sprite kit that is most likely the reason. Do not expect it to work with sprite kit.

Comment: @Jelly YES! I think that's the reason, I change to use SkEffectNode to do the blur job, and it works like a charm! Thanks so much Jelly! But I'm still wondering why this works okay on simulator but not on device? maybe they update scene differently? not sure

Comment: @Jelly can you write a short answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIVisualEffectView` does not work with `SpriteKit`. I don't know what they do differently in the back, if someone knows please feel free to edit the answer. My guess is that the underlying implementation use different APIs that don't work togheter. The simulator does all kinds of tricks to simulate the actual device so they might use something different in the back than the real devices and that's why it does work on a simulator.

Answer (score -1):

Remove this line in your code

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: not relevant...